# Make outer div be automatically the same height as its floating content

Tags: css, html, css-float

I want the outer `div`, which is black to wrap its `div`s floating within it. I dont want to use `style='height: 200px` in the `div` with the `outerdiv` id as I want it to be automatically the height of its content (eg, the floating `div`s).

```
<div id='outerdiv' style='border: 1px solid black;background-color: black;'>
<div style='width=300px;border: red 1px dashed;float: left;'>
    <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
</div>

<div style='width=300px;border: red 1px dashed;float: right;'>
    <p>zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</p>
</div>
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

You can set the `outerdiv`'s CSS to this

```
#outerdiv {
    overflow: hidden; /* make sure this doesn't cause unexpected behaviour */
}
```

You can also do this by adding an element at the end with `clear: both`. This can be added normally, with JS (not a good solution) or with `:after` CSS pseudo element (not widely supported in older IEs).

The problem is that containers won't naturally expand to include floated children. Be warned with using the first example, if you have any children elements outside the parent element, they will be hidden. You can also use 'auto' as the property value, but this will invoke scrollbars if any element appears outside.

You can also try floating the parent container, but depending on your design, this may be impossible/difficult.

Comment: I wish i understood the logic of why overflow: hidden works in this case.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping it wasn't just me who thought this was counter-intuitive. alex?

Comment: @regularmike I read an explanation once, I'll keep an eye out for it and link it back if I find it.

Comment: @masteroleary @regularmike `HTML/CSS` has never been good UI technology, so counter-intuitive things in it are quite common :)

Comment: @masteroleary I realize this is an old thread, but I recently tried to answer a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041297#21041625 -- hope it helps

Comment: +1 for the `float` solution. Works very well with the others fail, especially when paired with Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: @regularmike CSS counter-intuitve?  Never!

Comment: What if you can not have overflow hidden? In my case content is just hidden onder the screen.. can't scroll down even when there is content.

Comment: @NicolasV There is an alternative solution in the paragraph below the example CSS.

Comment: @alex Should have noted that I also tried that solution.. No luck

Answer (score 18):

Firstly, I highly recommend you do your CSS styling in an external CSS file, rather than doing it inline. It's much easier to maintain and can be more reusable using classes.

Working off Alex's answer (& Garret's clearfix) of "adding an element at the end with clear: both", you can do it like so:

```
    <div id='outerdiv' style='border: 1px solid black; background-color: black;'>
        <div style='width: 300px; border: red 1px dashed; float: left;'>
            <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
        </div>

        <div style='width: 300px; border: red 1px dashed; float: right;'>
            <p>zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</p>
        </div>
        <div style='clear:both;'></div>
    </div>
```

This works (but as you can see inline CSS isn't so pretty).

Comment: Why did I get rated down?
It works, and I rightly acknowledged that it wasn't a pretty solution.

Comment: I'm not sure, I +1'd to get you back to 0 at least. Maybe you were voted down because you didn't correct his incorrect CSS... i.e. using equals sign to set a CSS property is incorrect.

Comment: fair enough. I appreciate the +1 alex. I thought it was my statement was a fair one.

Comment: This solution is better IMO. I would have accept this answer if it was my question.

Answer (score 8):

You may want to try self-closing floats, as detailed on http://www.sitepoint.com/simple-clearing-of-floats/

So perhaps try either `overflow: auto` (usually works), or `overflow: hidden`, as alex said.

Comment: hidden works, but you're right, auto works that bit better. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I know some people will hate me, but I've found `display:table-cell` to help in this cases.

It is really cleaner.

Comment: outer div use display: table;
and inside div use display: table-cell;

Comment: I used display: table-cell on only outer div and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you don't use `width=300px` that's an attribute setting for the tag not CSS, use `width: 300px;` instead.

I would suggest applying the `clearfix` technique on the `#outerdiv`. [Clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) is a general solution to clear 2 floating divs so the parent div will expand to accommodate the 2 floating divs.

```
<div id='outerdiv' class='clearfix' style='width:600px; background-color: black;'>
    <div style='width:300px; float: left;'>
        <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
    </div>

    <div style='width:300px; float: left;'>
        <p>zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is an [example](http://www.webtoolkit.info/demo/css/clearfix/demo.html) of your situation and what Clearfix does to resolve it.

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery:

Set Parent Height = Child offsetHeight.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(parent).css("height", $(child).attr("offsetHeight"));
}
```

Comment: Overkill, when you can do it with CSS alone.

Comment: With my answer you can set parent height same as child hight but using overflow we are not changing parent height that will create some problem if we are showing data after parent div.

Answer (score 3):

Add a new, empty `div` just before the closing tag of the parent with this style: `clear: both;`.  Like this: `<div style="clear:both"></div>`.

I spent over a week trying to figure this out!

Comment: where to use clear: both ? I used in on the container div and nothing changed.

Comment: <div class='container-div'>[left-aligned divs all here]<div style='clear:both;'></div></div>. for example see next answers.