# Aligning a Child Div in a parent div

Tags: css, html, parent, alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make outer div be automaticly the same height as its floating content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804926/make-outer-div-be-automaticly-the-same-height-as-its-floating-content)

I feel like I'm missing something very simple here...

We have a simple setup: a parent div that contains a child div.
I want to:

- make the parent resize its height based on the child
- align the child to the right edge of the parent instead of the default left.

Using `float:right` will cause the parent to no longer resize correctly and the child to 'jump out' of the parent.

I've tried using `align: right` and `text-align: right` but so far no dice.

## HTML:

```
    <div id="parent"> <p>parent</p>
        <div class="child"> <p>child</p> </div>

        <div class="child right"> <p>child2</p> </div>
    </div>
```

## CSS:

```
    div{ padding: 15px; margin: 5px; }
    p{ padding: 0; margin: 0; }

    #parent{
        background-color: orange;
        width: 500px;
    }

    .child{
        background-color: grey;
        height: 200px;
        width: 100px;
    }

    .right{ float: right; } // note: as the commenters suggested I should also be using a float:left on the other child.
```

### [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tpg6i.png):

[image: result]

### [What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QASs3.png):

[image: what I want]

Any suggestions on what I could change either with `#parent` or `.right` to make `child2` align to the right properly?

## EDIT

The best fix I found for this is just using `display:table` on the parent. Though I haven't tested this in IE it fixes the issue in the browsers I care for and avoids using the un-intuitive `overflow:hidden` method discussed in the comments.

Even better: set margin-left of the child to auto.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804926/make-outer-div-be-automaticly-the-same-height-as-its-floating-content

Answer (score 9):

Try floating the contents and adding `overflow: hidden` to the parent. It's counter-intuitive but worked for me with a similar issue.

**EDIT:** Also float the first child to the left.

Comment: you could also use float:left on .child and float:right on .child + .child

Comment: What the... You're correct, adding overflow:hidden to the parent makes floated divs once again be encompassed by the parent div. This is incredibly counter-intuitive...

Comment: Would there happen to be an alternative that doesn't use overflow:hidden? unfortunately in the actual project I wanted this for I have a `position:relative` div that overlaps the parent which now gets cut off.

Comment: I figured out a way without using `overflow`. I just had to add `display:table` to the parent.