# DIV wrapper with 3 floating divs inside

Tags: html, position, css-float

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make outer div be automaticly the same height as its floating content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804926/make-outer-div-be-automaticly-the-same-height-as-its-floating-content)

Hi I have code like this

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id='float-left-1'>...</div>
    <div id='float-left-2'>...</div>
    <div id='float-left-3'>...</div>
</div>
```

When I run this page it happens that wrapper is not around divs inside... How can I solve this? Float divs are over the wrapper...

Thanks for answer in advance!

Comment: Thanks for down-vote but it didn't work for me... Now it works!

Comment: What didn't work for you. The linked post? If it didn't work for you why did you came up with the exact same solution?

Comment: I don't have specific height but it vary. Although whatever... The problem is solved and it might help someone. The trick was in position:relative and the solution suggested in upper link.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem...

All the float divs were added:

```
position: relative;
float: left;
```

at the end I have added:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

and now it works perfect... it did the trick!