# How do I make a div height depend on the content inside?

Tags: css, html

I have nested `div`s, with most being `float:left; display:block;`, like do:

```
<div class="container" style="display:block;">
    <div style="float:left; display:block; height:100px;">
    <div style="float:left; display:block; height:100px;">
</div>
```

I want the `div` container to get bigger without setting a height. At the moment it's a flat line.
How do I set up the inner `div`s, so that the container has a height?

**TL;DR**: Currently I can see the 2 inside `div`'s fine, but the container is a flat `div` (no height).
How do I give it a height?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two options:

```
<div class="container" style="overflow:hidden">
    <div style="float:left; height:100px;">
    <div style="float:left; height:100px;">
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="float:left; height:100px;">
    <div style="float:left; height:100px;">
    <div style="clear:left">
</div>
```

Note that `overflow:hidden` elements will wrap around floating inner elements. Alternatively, you can use an element to clear the float, which will also make the surrounding element to wrap it's content.

Another tip: You don't have to state that divs are `display:block`. In HTML, there are basically 2 types of elements, `block` and `inline`. Divs are `block` by default.

Comment: Do note that the value for the overflow attribute can be any value that is applicable (auto, hidden, scroll, visible).

Comment: Also, any floated element becomes a block.

Answer (score 3):

Add `overflow:hidden` to that DIV.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804926/make-outer-div-be-automaticly-the-same-height-as-its-floating-content

Comment: You can also float the container left or add a cleared element at the end (though I recommend using a clearfix solution)

Comment: Overflow: hidden can cause issues when you don't want the overflow to be hidden. (if you have a flyout for example). Clearfix is a good way to go as well.

Comment: Usually with floats you can't actually overflow, since you want it to fit, unless you add `max-height` or something, in which case, `overflow:auto` does the trick