# reset float after second column

Tags: css

I have the following layout:

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
   <div class="a"> test</div><div class="b">test2</div>
   <div class="a"> test</div><div class="b">test2</div>
   <div class="a"> test</div><div class="b">test2</div>
   <div class="a"> test</div><div class="b">test2</div>
   <div class="a"> test</div><div class="b">test2</div>
   <div class="a"> test</div><div class="b">test2</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test .a,.test .b {
  float: left;
  width: 100px; 
}

.test .a:nth-child(4n+1) , .test .b:nth-child(4n+2) { 
  background: lightgreen;
}


.test .b:after {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  content: "\a";  
}
```

it does not reset `float` after `.b`;

what I tried to acheive is two column list like

```
test test2
test test2
test test2
test test2
```

where both columns have fixed width

Is here any way to acheive my goal using only CSS ? (no html markup change)

http://jsbin.com/aJiMECE/12/edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `:nth-child()`:

```
.test .a:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tfXNj/)

To give the container div a width/background, you can add this (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804926/make-outer-div-be-automatically-the-same-height-as-its-floating-content)):

```
.test {
    background: red;
    width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tfXNj/2/)

Comment: that also nice, but this way `.test` do not expands to content :( 

http://jsbin.com/aJiMECE/9/edit in last block of this demo i show what I want to acheive, but this requered html change

Comment: can you please add this to answer ?

Comment: @eicto sorry for the late reply. I'm not sure why `inline-block` works tbh, but you can look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804926/make-outer-div-be-automatically-the-same-height-as-its-floating-content) for a better solution. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this? [**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/EMXSU/)

It seems to be the layout you are trying to achieve - unless I am missing something.

**CSS**

```
.test {
    width:200px;
}
.test > div {
    width:100px;
}
.a {
    float:left;
}
.b {
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: no way if I still want to have `.test` not match width of summ collumns? like here: http://jsbin.com/aJiMECE/2/edit

The idea is to have .test as independed block;

Comment: @eicto Still not fully understanding.. `.a` / `.b` will have fixed widths - but the parent, `.test` shouldn't? Which example are you trying to achieve..?

Comment: yes, or fixed width more than summ of them, I can make such layout using wrap for `.a` and `.b`, but just trying to understand if it necessary