# Why isn't overflow:auto required for text content?

Tags: css, html, css-float

In the following HTML snippet, how can I make the final paragraph appear under the 2 lists rather than to the right?

```
<div>
    <ul style="float: left;">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="float: left;">
        <li>item 4</li>
        <li>item 5</li>
        <li>item 6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <p>
        <!-- why the heck isn't this under the uls?! -->
        A final paragraph of text
    </p>
</div>
```

This HTML also available here: http://jsfiddle.net/8f2cE/

Also, I'd appreciate any background explanation as to why this behavior occurs at all. IMO this is inconsistent, because the 2 `div`s are root level have `display: block;` by default without any floating attributes set, so shouldn't they flow as "normal" from top to bottom down the page?

Answer (score 10):

When you float an element, it is *removed from the normal flow* (see first paragraph of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float), and therefore will float left (or right) of whatever content follows (your `<div>` and `<p>`), and also its container will not stretch to its floated content by default. (in other words, `display: block;` alone does not contain floats).

To make an element contain its floats, you can either put an element with `clear` after your floats (as the other answers here suggest, ignoring your question title...), **or you can apply `overflow: auto;`** to the containing element, which is one of the properties which will **trigger the [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)**.

(text below from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context))

> Block formatting contexts are important for the positioning (see
>   float) and clearing (see clear) of floats. The rules for positioning
>   and clearing of floats apply only to things within the same block
>   formatting context. Floats do not affect the layout of things in other
>   block formatting contexts, and clear only clears past floats in the
>   same block formatting context.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after the first `div`. As you are adding style `float: left;`, uls are losing their original position.

```
<div>
  <ul style="float: left;">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul style="float: left;">
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div>
  <p>
    <!-- why the heck isn't this under the uls?! -->
    A final paragraph of text
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are giving `float:left` to ul, parent `div` loses its height.

Write:

```
div{overflow:hidden;}
```

This will give height to div.

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/8f2cE/1/)

OR

Clear the floats:

```
<div>
    <ul style="float: left;">
        .......
    </ul>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clr{clear:both;}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/8f2cE/2/)

Comment: Please help to answer this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21042510/getting-ruby-value-in-jquery#21042510

Answer (score 0):

You should use a clearer with float divs:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

like this:

```
<div>
<ul style="float: left;">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul style="float: left;">
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div>
    <p>
         <!-- why the heck isn't this under the uls?! -->
         A final paragraph of text
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra `div` as specified by the other answers or add `overflow:auto; width:10%` to the first div itself

```
<div style="overflow: auto;width:100%">
    <ul style="float: left;">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="float: left;">
        <li>item 4</li>
        <li>item 5</li>
        <li>item 6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <p>
        <!-- why the heck isn't this under the uls?! -->
        A final paragraph of text
    </p>
</div>
```

Source : http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: From reading the title, apparently he knows he *can* do this, the question is why does it work.