# getting ruby value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a textarea in which I am populating a database record. I want to access the same value in textarea in jquery.

```
<textarea id="contact_address1"><%= @contact[:address1] %></textarea>
```

How do I do it? Pleasse help!

Comment: Have you tried your code? How does it fail?

Comment: @JanDvorak I dont know how to access the value <%= @contact[:address1] %> in jquery. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is jQuery's `val()` function:

```
$( "textarea#contact_address1").val();
```

Take a look: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: It doesnt work. Already tried!

Comment: What do you mean? Can you show us what you've tried? Have you put this into a JS file and loaded the file? Have you debugged what the value is?

Comment: value is showing undefined

Comment: @DarkKnight are you sure the textarea is already loaded?

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes it has data. But cant access it in jquery! Has it got somthing to do with ruby?

Comment: I mean, are you using `$(document).ready` or placing the script after the  element?

Comment: @JanDvorak I have placed it inside the $(document).ready element

Comment: @DarkKnight I've misread your code by speed :) Updated my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Agis don't look at me. I haven't asked. I have voted to close.

Comment: @Agis no .text() gives the initial value not the current value.

Comment: @DarkKnight is correct, if you want current value, use `.val()` http://jsfiddle.net/K5e66/

Comment: @DarkKnight oops you're right, reverted to my initial answer. So it still shows 'undefined'? Can you paste your view and your JS code please?

Comment: @Agis I am using ruby on rails. 
My view:
<textarea id="contact_address1"><%= @contact[:address1] %></textarea>

What i tried for accessing the same and didnt work:
$( "textarea#contact_address1").val();
$( "textarea#contact_address1").text();

These are the relevant things. Do i have to use ajax?

Comment: @DarkKnight This doesn't help. But pasting your actual view file and your JS file would help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#contant_address1").text();
```

and let be sure that the id of your `textarea` should be "contant_address1".

Comment: *and let be sure that the id of your textarea should be "contant_address1".* ..but surely, you can tell from the OP code that the ID is `contact_address1` (not "contant"!)

Comment: "contact_address1" put it in jquery syntax and try.